# ps-print-buffer error

Tags: print

I cannot get ps-pinting working in emacs I have a lisp file, and when I try to translate to ps I only get the file with an error

C-u M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces

I get this file:

https://ufile.io/1f0f0

It has an error

I'm using Mac Os Sierra, emacs 26.0, but the same configuration on other cmputer but with Captain works, I user the same .emacs.d for both emacs, for example converting an org file to latex pdf it works well in both environments

Comment: Your ps-file has all headers but no content. Just tested `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` with some large emacs-lisp file. Works fine for me. System: GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: I tested it with a buffer with lisp code

Comment: updated with systminfo

Comment: I can see the same problem on Mac OS X Sierra with Emacs 26.0.50 (built from source).  Emacs 25.1.1 (from https://emacsformacosx.com/) on the same machine works just fine.

Comment: I do not get any error message, it is inside de ps you can read it with emacs, it is too long and I'm not sure of which part it is important

Comment: @Drew There is no error message in the ps file. I think the OP misinterprets the definitions in the header of the ps file as error messages. The ps header is more or less the same as that one of my working test ps-file. In his version the second year in the copyright message is 2017 whereas in my it is 2016. More important is that in his version the font definitions below `%% End of Mule Section` are missing.  In his version behind the mule comment there follows immediately `BeginDoc` in my version there is additional stuff like `/F00 /Courier findfont def`.

Comment: @Drew ...Continuation... As I stated above the section between `BeginDoc`  and `EndDoc` is empty in his ps file (up to some irrelevant ps comments). In my version there stands the actual document content there.

Comment: I finally downgrade emacs to 25.2.1 and now it is working well